# QR Code detection?

Tags: ros, visp-auto-tracker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am developing a project which makes use of visp_auto_tracker, among other packages.
The visp code allows to keep track of a QR o flashcode:
[visp_auto_tracker](http://www.ros.org/wiki/visp_auto_tracker?distro=groovy)

But it doesn't make any difference between QR codes (the package doesn't read them).

**Is there any ROS QR Code detection package OR project available?**

If there isn't, i'm planning to make a Java node that deciphers QR code from an image and present the result with a ROS message (or something similar).

Any help is appreciated.
Many greetings ROS community.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59623/qr-code-detection?/) by [aimc](https://answers.ros.org/users/3966/aimc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 216 on 2013-03-30

Post score: 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are some packages that do QR or generic barcode detection, but they are usually part of a stack and thus hard to use on their own. It would be nice to have a generic package for barcode detection.

The package I know of is [cob_marker](http://www.ros.org/wiki/cob_marker), which is part of cob_object_perception stack. It does require RGB-d sensor such as Kinect.

I have also written my own package for the task I had, namely simulating the Player's laser barcode driver. It only uses camera and estimates the barcode location based on a preset barcode size (not very precise). [zbar_barcode_reader](http://git.io/zbar_barcode_reader)

---

Originally posted by [mmedvede](https://answers.ros.org/users/1773/mmedvede/) with karma: 221 on 2013-05-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [hector_qrcode_detection](https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_vision/tree/master/hector_qrcode_detection) package we use on our Rescue Robots (see [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=olGZv05RLHI), all the 44 blue dots are QR codes detected via 3 onboard cameras) is available. There´s no extensive documentation, but here´s the [launch file used on Hector UGV](https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_vision/blob/master/hector_qrcode_detection/launch/qrcode_detection.launch) and looking at the [code](https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_vision/blob/master/hector_qrcode_detection/src/qrcode_detection.cpp)  should provide enough information about the interface and potential changes that are required for your use case.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-06-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2